# "it" in the sentence "on Thursday after the event's organizers it announced,,,,"

Tags: meaning, grammar, syntactic-analysis

Can anyone explain "it" after "organisers" in the sentence

- on Thursday after the event's organisers it announced that it would be held virtually ...".

This is [from an] [on-line article of Herald-Dispatch.com](https://www.herald-dispatch.com/trump-pulls-out-of-next-debate-after-organizers-say-it-will-be-held-online-because/article_ed63d4c3-6474-5f0f-ae30-0b3e59c344c2.html)

In the same sentence by another Publisher "it" was used (I do not remember the Author or Publisher.) while "it" was not used in the same sentence in many other articles.

To me "it" should not be used after "organizers" .  It just does not make sense to me. However I often see this kind of "it".

Comment: Looks like the reporter was in a hurry. The sentence is ungrammatical. Sometimes they do this on purpose to make it _look like_ they are reporting  breaking news.

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. Check the wording in the link itself: "say-it-will-be-held-online," not "it announced that it".

Comment: Without prior context, any referent for that 'it' is guesswork. Possibly 'it' is a mistake for 'it was'.

Comment: @Edwin: if you look at the full text, it's clearly an extraneous word. I expect the original text was "after it was announced", and the slavering hordes of passive-haters pounced on it and demanded an edit (which was bungled).

Comment: @TonyK Probably true, a nasty case of passive-case-ism looks likely.